# How do you set a specific column with a specific value to a new value in a Pandas DF?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements

I imported a CSV file that has two columns ID and Bee_type. The bee_type has two types in it - bumblebee and honey bee. I'm trying to convert them to numbers instead of names; i.e. instead of bumblebee it says 1.

However, my code is setting everything to 1. How can I keep the ID column its original value and only change the bee_type column?

```
# load the labels using pandas
labels = pd.read_csv("bees/train_labels.csv")

#Set bumble_bee to one
for index in range(len(labels)):
    labels[labels['bee_type'] == 'bumble_bee'] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary if only 2 possible values exist:

```
labels['bee_type'] = labels['bee_type'].map({'bumble_bee': 1, 'honey_bee': 2})
```

Another solution is to use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) - set values by condition:

```
labels['bee_type'] = np.where(labels['bee_type'] == 'bumble_bee', 1, 2)
```

Your code works, but for improved performance, modify it a bit - remove loops and add `loc`:

```
labels.loc[labels['bee_type'] == 'bumble_bee'] = 1
print (labels)
   ID   bee_type
0   1          1
1   1  honey_bee
2   1          1
3   3  honey_bee
4   1          1
```

**Sample**:

```
labels = pd.DataFrame({
    'bee_type': ['bumble_bee','honey_bee','bumble_bee','honey_bee','bumble_bee'],
    'ID': list(range(5))
})
print (labels)
   ID    bee_type
0   0  bumble_bee
1   1   honey_bee
2   2  bumble_bee
3   3   honey_bee
4   4  bumble_bee

labels['bee_type'] = labels['bee_type'].map({'bumble_bee': 1, 'honey_bee': 2})
print (labels)
   ID  bee_type
0   0         1
1   1         2
2   2         1
3   3         2
4   4         1
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you.

Comment: Anytime my friend!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you want to convert names to numbers. If that's the scenario please try LabelEncoder. Detailed documentation can be found [sklearn LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)